# is ggplot2.layer fully supported in Rpy2?

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, rpy2

I am trying to use ggplot2 `layer` in my graph plotted via Rpy2, which I don' see described in the manual (http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/graphics.html)

Is the correct form for calling the `layer` function the following? From R,

```
p <- p + layer(data=df, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y, label=foo), geom='text', hjust=1, vjust=1)
```

Should be in Rpy2:

```
p += ggplot2.layer(**{"data": df,
                      "mapping": ggplot2.aes_string(x="x", y="y", label="foo"),
                      "geom": "text"})
                      "hjust": 1,
                      "vjust": 1})
```

When I try this, I get errors like:

```
TypeError: new() got an unexpected keyword argument 'vjust'
```

and:

```
TypeError: new() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mapping'
```

Just wondering if this is the correct way to add a `layer` to a plot from Rpy2, or if there's a different idiom? thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `layer` at all, rather than the typical `geom_*` and `stat_*` functions?

Comment: It's the only way I found to do this: `plt <- qplot(data=iris, x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length) + facet_wrap(~Species); plt <- plt + layer(data=textdf.a, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y, label=textdf.b), geom='text', hjust=1, vjust=1)` a way to annotate the scatter plots made by this `qplot` call. I am open to alternatives.

Comment: Tips: Stop using `qplot` entirely, and switch to `ggplot()`. (Basically) never use `layer`. There is always a specific `geom_*` function that is equivalent. In this case, `geom_text()`.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm new to R. Could you show the equivalent `geom_text` call with `ggplot` please? I was unable to get it to work. Also, just curious, why not `qplot` - what's wrong with it?

Comment: It's no different really: `geom_text(data = textdf.a,aes(...),hjust = ...,vjust = ...)`.

Comment: Great, for some reason the `geom_text` call works in ggplot2 via Rpy2 but the layer doesn't. Good enough for me. Still curious about why you dislike layer/qplot. Anyway, if you put your comment as an answer I'll accept that as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: @joran, post as answer?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Sorry, I'm on my phone and about to fall asleep. Anyone's free to answer...

Comment: @joran, hahah, what a great way to end the night ;)   Nothing like a little SO

Comment: It is a bug in rpy2's wrapping of ggplot2 (`vjust` and `mapping` are not mapped).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do it (answered in the comments).

Beside that there was a bug in rpy2 preventing parameters parameters to `layer()` to be specified, now (hopefully) fixed in both branches `version_2.3.x` (will be included with release 2.3.3) and `default`.